# How to know 8.3 name of a GIVEN object in Windows?

Tags: windows, filenames

Suppose I have GIVEN file or folder.

GIVEN mean it is current folder in command line mode or some icon in the GUI.

How to know it's 8.3 (short) name and/or path?

I know I can find this object location on disk, go one level up, and issue `dir /x` command.

But this is very long since require a lot of excess operations, including search of possible long list of entries and looking for long name there and remembering short name from there.

I would like to have some simple command like

`pwdshort`

or some explorer context menu option.

Is it possible?

Comment: is there a reason you need to use 8.3 name?

Comment: Some instructions require to set 8.3 paths for products with compatibility issues

Comment: What should be the result of performing the steps (whatever they might be; I imagine Powershell might be useful) if the system has short file names disabled?

Comment: Don't you mean long file names?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling some message about absence or error code

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to have a context menu for this is to add an entry to the already available "Send to" context menu.
For this open an explorer window and in the address box type "sendto" this will take you to your sendto folder where you can define new send to actions.

Right-click->New->"Text document" and rename the newly created empty txt file to e.g. shortname.bat, just press ok if it complains that you change the file extensions.

Write the following commands into this new file and save it:

```
@echo %~fs1
pause
```

Now you should have a new sendto target called "shortname". If you send to it, a cmd window will appear with the shortname printed out, press any key to close the window.